# adding event listener of the closing and changing the FLA document for the SWF extension panel. using ActionScript, JSFL

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe, jsfl

I have an extension SWF panel and a list of movie clips of the currently open document on it. I want to clear my list when the user closes the current document. Also, I want to add some alert "You have to select the previous document you were work on" - when the user selects other open .fla document and tries to press some button on the SWF panel to edit some MC from the list. So I want to know if has Adobe Animate the ability to listen to closing and changing of documents?
thank you for advance for any hints

Answer (score 1):

an answer from adobe community support:

Yes, there is such a possibility. You can register a javascript function to be executed when certain system event occurs:

`enter code here`fl.addEventListener( eventType, callbackFunction );

The possible system events are:
"documentNew", "documentOpened", "documentClosed", "mouseMove", "documentChanged", "layerChanged", "timelineChanged", "frameChanged", “”, "prePublish", "postPublish", "selectionChanged", and "dpiChanged".

Also, in Flash CS4 and above, you have the possibility to refer a particular swf panel. In combination with ExternalInterface class and MMExecute method in AS, you can build a two-way communication between the two environments.

Example:

// JSFL

`var docChangedID = fl.addEventListener( "documentChanged"`, `onDocumentChangedHandler );`

`function onDocumentChangedHandler(){`

`var panel = fl.getSwfPanel( "<my panel swf file name >", false );`
`panel.call( "AScustomEventName" );`
`}`

// AS

`import adobe.utils.MMExecute;`
`import flash.external.ExternalInterface;`

`ExternalInterface.addCallback( "AScustomEventName", this.myASMethod );`

`function myASMethod() : void {`
`// your stuff here`
`MMExecute( "some jsfl code or path to a jsfl script" );`
`}`